# Passing pointers and more

Tags: c++, function, pointers, memory, memory-management

In general, I always pass pointers through functions of any objects I create; if I need something done to an object, I would pass it by pointer rather than by reference. That's just a programming habit which some might describe as miniscule; but this is where I have to ask by example:

```
class someObject
{
   public:
      someObject();
      ~someObject();

      void do(const char* smth)
      {
          cout << smth << endl;
      }

   private:
};

class doObject
{
    public:
       doObject();
       ~doObject();

       void takeObject(someObject *so)
       {
           pObject = so;
           so->do("Hi");
       }

    private:
       someObject *pObject;
}
```

And in main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    someObject *so = new someObject();
    so->do();

    doObject *do = new doObject();
    do->takeObject(so);

    delete so;
    delete do;
}
```

1. Should memory be allocated to doObject::pObject BEFORE it is assigned the pointer parameter so of type someObject?
2. If pObject is assigned the foresaid parameter, should it be deleted; e.g. delete pObject?
3. In main.cpp someObject is deleted BEFORE doObject is. This is vital to understand because doObject has an assignment of someObject called pObject. Deleting someObject before doObject means there's a dangling pointer which implies any actions on it would produce a segmentation fault.
4. If I delete doObject first in main.cpp, does that also delete pObject AS WELL AS 'so' of type someObject? After all, they are linked.
5. If I create a new class that also a function which also requires a parameter of someObject, does that mean pObject no longer points to 'so'? Should I instead use a shared pointer so that it's possible for both classes to be able to point to 'so' and change the object as necessary?
6. How can the code be improved? Should I consider the use of smart pointers to ensure that I do not delete an object more than once in various parts of a program?

Yes, the question is rather complex; but that's what you get with pointers!

Comment: That's a lot of questions in one question.  Additionally: You can't call a method or a variable **do**, it's a keyword.  Always make sure your short examples like this can at least compile...as otherwise it will obscure the conversation!

Comment: Use smart pointer to avoid to manage memory yourself.

Comment: _@Poriferous_ _"Yes, the question is rather complex; "_ No. The design looks rather flawed. _"but that's what you get with pointers!"_ Exactly. You don't use them in serious C++ programming.

Comment: Holy hannah! _One_ question per question, please. The clue's in the word "question"...

Comment: All the questions are tied together; it's better than spamming questions that are all related. I did put in 'and more' in the question. Regardless, I will attempt to improve the code with smart pointers instead and see how it goes.

Comment: Maybe it would have been better to realize that the question-cluster wasn't the best fit for SO, then. If you cannot distill it to focused, concrete question about something you're actually implementing, then... well chances are it's off topic anyway

Comment: Regardless, my question has been answered and we got the best of all worlds now. Thanks!

Comment: True. The example was a lot more "answerable" than the individual questions, IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Should memory be allocated to doObject::pObject BEFORE it is assigned the pointer parameter so of type someObject?

Memory is allocated in `main` and a pointer to that memory is assigned to `so`. The member variable `pObject` will just point at the same object as `so` does. So memory *is* allocated before you assigne the member pointer variable.

> 2. If pObject is assigned the foresaid parameter, should it be deleted; e.g. delete pObject?

Someone must delete the object pointed at to not get a memory leak. Either *someone* does it or the ownership is *shared*. You decide if you transfer the ownership when you pass the pointer to another function, or not. Being consistent is the key and using smart pointers is a help.

> 3. In main.cpp someObject is deleted BEFORE doObject is. This is vital to understand because doObject has an assignment of someObject called pObject. Deleting someObject before doObject means there's a dangling pointer which implies any actions on it would produce a segmentation fault.

If you allocate dynamic memory, always deallocate in reverse allocation order to prevent dangling pointers.

> 4. If I delete doObject first in main.cpp, does that also delete pObject AS WELL AS 'so' of type someObject? After all, they are linked.

No. If the `doObject` destructor had done `delete pObject;`, then it would.

> 5. If I create a new class that also a function which also requires a parameter of someObject, does that mean pObject no longer points to 'so'? Should I instead use a shared pointer so that it's possible for both classes to be able to point to 'so' and change the object as necessary?

`pObject` *doesn't* point at `so`, it points at the same dynamically allocated object as `so` does. Any number of pointers to that object can exist in any number of classes, but it's your resonsibility to make sure that after the object is deleed, no holder of a pointer to it uses that pointer. That's why it's important to dlete objects in the correct order.

> 6. How can the code be improved? Should I consider the use of smart pointers to ensure that I do not delete an object more than once in various parts of a program?

Yes, smart pointers if you want to share the ownership (`shared_ptr`) or ensure there's just one owner (`unique_ptr`), or have the guideline that a pointer parameter is *only* referring to an instance, never owning.

Also use automatic instances where possible instead of dynamic.

Comment: No.4 is not true. Deleting doObject does not delete someObject.

Answer (score -3):

> 6. How can the code be improved? Should I consider the use of smart pointers to ensure that I do not delete an object more than once in various parts of a program?

I'd recommend learning manual memory management first and once you've mastered it, then start using smart pointers. But of course you can jump straight into smart pointers if you think you don't need to know manual memory management.

Comment: I'd recommend literally the exact opposite of this recommendation.

Comment: I don't think there are any valid reasons for learning MMM *before* smart pointers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Interesting. Care to explain why?

Comment: It's easy to explain. You can just turn the question around: "Should you consider making it possible to delete an object more than once in various parts of a program?" (Also noteworthy: you didn't care to explain your recommendation either)